# Python logger to dictionary

Tags: python

I am new in python...i am trying to read a python log file and make a dictionary. How  will it be done with logger?

Comment: What sort of dictionary? What sort of log file? Please show a sample of your input and your intended output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best tool to parse log files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994355/whats-the-best-tool-to-parse-log-files)

Answer (score 1):

> read a python log file and make a dictionary. How will it be done with logger?

It won't.

`logging` writes logs.

`file` reads logs.

What are you asking?

First, search for [Python] log parsing:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+log+parsing

Second, please post some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

As other commenter said, you don't want to use `logging` to read the file, instead use `file`. Here's an example of writing a log file, then reading it back.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# logger.py -- will write "time:debug:A:1" "time:debug:B:2" "time:debug:A:3" etc. log entries to a file
import logging, random
logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
for i in range(1,100): logging.debug("%s:%d" % (random.choice(["a", "b"]), i))
# logfile.log now contains --
# 100.1:debug:A:1
# 100.5:debug:B:2
# 100.8:debug:B:3
# 101.3:debug:A:4
# ....
# 130.3:debug:B:100

#!/usr/bin/env/python
# reader.py -- will read aformentioned log files and sum up the keys
handle = file.open('logfile.log', 'r')
sums = {}
for line in handle.readlines():
  time, debug, key, value = line.split(':')
  if not key in sums: sums[key] = 0
  sums[key] += value
print sums
# will output -- 
# "{'a': 50, 'b': 50}"
```