# Want to process a large appengine log file

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, logfiles

I run my app on google app engine.....My log files are huge due to heavy traffic
The log file looks like this

```
122.167.221.243 - - [06/Mar/2012:01:11:29 -0800] "GET /Bengali/enable HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "http://www.epicsearch.in/" -
---Similar rows ---- below
```

I want to process them to get meaningful stats such as no. of unique IP addresses or no. of hits on a given page....
I am a beginner so do not know how to go about it!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't already done so, the first thing you'll want to do is [download your App Engine logs](http://blog.dantup.com/2009/12/downloadingexporting-app-engine-logs.html) using the `appcfg.py` utility, for example:

```
appcfg.py --num_days=5 request_logs appname/ logs.txt
```

After you download it, you will have to throw together a script or program to **parse** your logs for whatever information **you** deem useful.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1994355/1101070) Stack Overflow question might be a good place to start -- really any decent scripting language should be able to adequately parse those logs for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.....I had already downloaded the log file... I will look into some script to parse data